# Lookup for 2nd, 3rd, ..nth match and return sorting results from smallest to largest values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have tried searching on google but I didn't find the solution yet. 
I would like to lookup the value that match with conditions and return result with sorting from small to large. What formula should i use to do this?
Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have duplicate values in `Time` column, the following array formula can help :

```
{=IFERROR(SMALL(IF(($D2=$A$2:$A$12)*($B$2:$B$12>=TIME(7,0,0))*($B$2:$B$12<=TIME(10,0,0)),IF(COUNTIF($D2:D2,$B$2:$B$12)=0,$B$2:$B$12)),1),"")}
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would use the SMALL function of Aggregate:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$B$2:$B$10/
(($A$2:$A$10=$D2)*($B$2:$B$10>=TIME(7,0,0))*($B$2:$B$10<=TIME(10,0,0))),COLUMN(A1)),"")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve multiple matching values from a set of data with a formula, you can use the IF and SMALL functions to figure out the row number of each match and feed that value back to INDEX.

```
{=INDEX(array,SMALL(IF(vals=val,ROW(vals)-ROW(INDEX(vals,1,1))+1),nth))}
```

Where:

- **array:** 1 column range containing the results -> Column: B:B
- **vals:** 1 column lookup array -> Column: A:A
- **val:** lookup value -> Column: D:D
- **nth** -> Change row 1 values to 1,2,3,4 etc. instead of 1st, 2nd 3rd...

As always when working with array formulas, use ctrl+shift+enter instead of normal enter

Answer (score 1):

If you have `O365` with the `UNIQUE` function, you can use:

```
D2: =UNIQUE(Name) 'to generate the list of names

E2: =IFERROR(SMALL(FILTER(Name:Time,(Name=$D2)*(Time>=TIME(7,,))*(Time <=TIME(10,,))),COLUMNS($A:A)),"")
```

Select `E2` and copy across and down

[image]